# How can I read a data file into fortran 95?

Tags: formatting, fortran

How can I get fortran to read the following data in a txt file?

```
    22        20
    0.       10.         1       16.
    0.        0.         1       16.
   10.       10.         0       16.
   10.        0.         0       16.
   20.       10.         0       16.
   20.        0.         0       16.
   30.       10.         0       16.
   30.        0.         0       16.
   40.       10.         0       16.
   40.        0.         0       16.
   50.       10.         0       16.
   50.        0.         0       16.
   60.       10.         0       16.
   60.        0.         0       16.
   70.       10.         0       16.
   70.        0.         0       16.
   80.       10.         0       16.
   80.        0.         0       16.
   90.       10.         0       16.
   90.        0.         0       16.
  100.       10.         1       11.
  100.        0.         1       11.
     1         2         4
     1         4         3
     3         4         6
     3         6         5
     5         6         8
     5         8         7
     7         8        10
     7        10         9
     9        10        12
     9        12        11
    11        12        14
    11        14        13
    13        14        16
    13        16        15
    15        16        18
    15        18        17
    17        18        20
    17        20        19
    19        20        22
    19        22        21
```

Hi have tried doing this below but i am only able to read the first 2 rows, i need it to read it all.

```
program FILEREADER

   real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: x
   integer :: n,m

   open (unit=99, file='data.txt', status='old', action='read')
   read(99, *), n
   read(99, *), m
   allocate(x(n,m))

   do I=1,n,1
      read(99,*) x(I,:)
      write(*,*) x(I,:)
   enddo

end
```

This is the result i get:

```
              0         0.000         0.000         0.000         0.000              
             22        20.000         0.000        10.000         1.000
```

Comment: Based on the format, it sounds like: 1) n= 22 (good), 2) m=20 (good), 3) you need to read 22 items into real array `x(22, 4)`, read 20 elements into integer array `a(20, 3)`.

Comment: I am new with fortran, may you add these changes to the code?

Comment: I do not understand where the changes would occur?

Comment: You have two differemt data sets, one of size `n` with four values each (real, the third seems to be an integer) and one of size `m` with three integers each. Your array `(n, m)` does not represent that structure. (The data looks like a set of ´n` vertices/nodes and `m` connecting triangles.)

Comment: This question seems to be a version of OP's earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37106186/how-can-i-get-my-fortran-95-code-to-read-data-from-a-text-file but the code shown here doesn't seem to show any awareness of the code shown there.

Comment: Please do not start new questions about the same problem without explaining what have you changed. Are those code snippets just some pieces of code you got somewhere? Or did you write them yourself? Getting several questions downvoted can lead to a ban of asking new questions.

Comment: Your problem is at least partly related to the ideas of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19421382).  That is, you want to read the values for `n` and `m` from the first (single) line, but you use two distinct advancing read statements.